# How can I play a video in an inline onclick handler?

Tags: javascript, video, onclick

I can play a video using an onclick function call (ex.1) but not using an inline clean call (ex.2). Why is that so?

ex1

```
  <script> 
  function p()
  {document.getElementById("myVideo").play();}
  </script>

  <video id="myVideo" width="100" height="100" controls loop>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <button onclick="p();">play</button>
```

ex2

```
  <video id="myVideo" width="100" height="100" controls loop>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById("myVideo").play();">play</button>
```

Comment: Please give us more details and also the error message or anything that happens after you click the button in ex2 so that we can have more information to work on and hence help solving the issue.

Comment: Using inline HTML events is considered a bad practice. Have a read here [`Why Inline CSS And JavaScript Code Is Such A Bad Thing`](https://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/)

Comment: You have nested single quote and double quote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> <button onclick="document.getElementById("myVideo").play();">play</button>
> ```

Your HTML attribute value is delimited with `"` characters, but you try to use `"` characters inside it to delimit the JS string literals.

Consequently, your attribute value is `document.getElementById(` (which is invalid JS which would be reported on the Console of the developer tools in your browser when you clicked the button) and `myVideo` starts a new attribute.

Use `&quot;` or `'` inside the attribute value.

Better yet, bind your event handlers with [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) (the prefered way since the late 1990s) instead of HTML.

Comment: Can you escape HTML attrs? such as: `<button onclick="document.getElementById(\"myVideo\").play();">play</button>`

Comment: @Alex — Not with ```\``` characters. See the penultimate paragraph of this answer for how to escape characters in HTML.

Comment: Cool, Just making sure! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do not nest single quote and double quote. use one of the followings:

```
onclick='document.getElementById("myVideo").play();'
```

or

```
onclick="document.getElementById('myVideo').play();"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can not use quotes inside other quotes.

I think this will work.

```
<video id="myVideo" width="100" height="100" controls loop>
<source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
      <button onclick="document.getElementById('myVideo').play();">play</button>
```